# listview.ScrollIntoView(listview.SelectedItem) is not working when repeated rows occurs in listview

Tags: wpf, listview, wpf-controls

WPF listview.ScrollIntoView(listview.SelectedItem) doesn't work, if items contain reference duplicates (repeated rows occur).

I am working on FINDNEXT functionality.

In my listview rows data are repeated. When repeated row appears it scrolls to the first occurrence of the duplicate.

How to scroll to the right item in `ListView`?

```
private void Listview_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

    listview.UpdateLayout();
    listview.ScrollIntoView(listview.SelectedItem);

}
```

Comment: Since you have reference duplicates it is better to deal with `SelectedIndex` not with `SelectedItem` as you search through the items and it's also tricky to make a row visible at definite index, but it's possible.

Comment: Avoid duplicate references altogether. For a duplicate item, create a new item instance with identical data.

Answer (score 0):

This solution needs the virtualisation be switched off, better way as Clemens offered - clone a duplicates for they are different objects, then you can use your approach.

```
private static DependencyObject FirstVisualChild(UIElement visual)
{
    if (visual == null)
        return null;
    if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(visual) == 0)
        return null;
    return VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(visual, 0);
}

private void Listview_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var itmFromIdx = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(listView.SelectedIndex);

    ScrollContentPresenter presenter = null;
    for (var vis = itmFromIdx as UIElement; vis != null; vis = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(vis) as UIElement)
        if ((presenter = vis as ScrollContentPresenter) != null)
            break;
    if (presenter == null)
        throw new Exception();

    var virtStackPnl = FirstVisualChild(presenter.Content as ItemsPresenter);//VirtualizingStackPanel

    (virtStackPnl as IScrollInfo).MakeVisible(itmFromIdx as UIElement, new Rect(new Size(0, 0)));
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ... VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False">
```